# How to use a window function to determine when to perform different tasks?

Tags: r, dplyr, window, dbplyr

Note: Similar question I have asked for SQL - [How to use a window function to determine when to perform different tasks in Hive or Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598730/how-to-use-a-window-function-to-determine-when-to-perform-different-tasks-in-hiv)

**Data**

I have a some data showing the start day and end day for different pre-prioritised tasks per person:

```
   input_df <- data.frame(person        = c(rep("Kate", 2), rep("Adam", 2), rep("Eve", 2), rep("Jason", 5)),
                       task_key   = c(c("A","B"), c("A","B"), c("A","B"), c("A","B","C","D","E")),
                       start_day     = c(c(1L,1L), c(1L,2L), c(2L,1L), c(1L,4L,3L,5L,4L)),
                       end_day       = 5L)
```

> ```
>    person      task_key start_day end_day
> 1    Kate             A         1       5
> 2    Kate             B         1       5
> 3    Adam             A         1       5
> 4    Adam             B         2       5
> 5     Eve             A         2       5
> 6     Eve             B         1       5
> 7   Jason             A         1       5
> 8   Jason             B         4       5
> 9   Jason             C         3       5
> 10  Jason             D         5       5
> 11  Jason             E         4       5
> ```

NOTE: Task key is ordered so that higher letters have higher priorities.

**Question**

I need to work out which task each person should be working on each day, with the condition that:

1. Higher lettered tasks take priority over lower lettered tasks.
2. If a higher lettered task overlaps any part of a lower lettered task, then the lower lettered task gets set to NA (to represent that the person should not work on it ever).

**Simplification**

In the real data the end_day is always 5 in the original table i.e. only the start_day varies but the end_day is constant. This means my desired output will have the same number of rows as my original table :)

**Output**

This is the sort of output I need (Jason is more representative of the data I have which can be over 100 tasks covering a period of 90 days):

```
output_df <- data.frame(person        = c(rep("Kate", 2), rep("Adam", 2), rep("Eve", 2), rep("Jason", 5)),
                        task_key   = c(c("A","B"), c("A","B"), c("A","B"), c("A","B","C","D","E")),
                        start_day     = c(c(1L,1L), c(1L,2L), c(2L,1L), c(1L,4L,3L,5L,4L)),
                        end_day       = 5L,
                        valid_from    = c( c(NA,1L), c(1L,2L), c(NA,1L), c(1L,NA,3L,NA,4L) ),
                        valid_to      = c( c(NA,5L), c(2L,5L), c(NA,5L), c(3L,NA,4L,NA,5L) ))
```

> ```
>    person    task_key start_day end_day valid_from valid_to
> 1    Kate           A         1       5         NA       NA
> 2    Kate           B         1       5          1        5
> 3    Adam           A         1       5          1        2
> 4    Adam           B         2       5          2        5
> 5     Eve           A         2       5         NA       NA
> 6     Eve           B         1       5          1        5
> 7   Jason           A         1       5          1        3
> 8   Jason           B         4       5         NA       NA
> 9   Jason           C         3       5          3        4
> 10  Jason           D         5       5         NA       NA
> 11  Jason           E         4       5          4        5
> ```

**Initial Thoughts**

Works but I want a solution that works using the dbplyr package functions and something that is generally better than this:

```
tmp            <- input_df %>% filter(person == "Jason")
num_rows       <- nrow(tmp)
tmp$valid_from <- NA
tmp$valid_to   <- NA

for(i in 1:num_rows) {
  # Curent value
  current_value <- tmp$start_day[i]

  # Values to test against
  vec <- lead(tmp$start, i)

  # test
  test <- current_value >= vec

  # result  
  if(any(test, na.rm = TRUE) & i!=num_rows) {
    tmp$valid_from[i] <- NA
    tmp$valid_to[i]   <- NA
  } else if(i!=num_rows) {
    tmp$valid_from[i] <- current_value 
    tmp$valid_to[i]   <- min(vec, na.rm = TRUE)
  } else {
    tmp$valid_from[i] <- current_value 
    tmp$valid_to[i]   <- max(tmp$end_day, na.rm = TRUE)
  }

}
tmp
```

> ```
>   person task_number start_day end_day valid_from valid_to
> 1  Jason           A         1       5          1        3
> 2  Jason           B         4       5         NA       NA
> 3  Jason           C         3       5          3        4
> 4  Jason           D         5       5         NA       NA
> 5  Jason           E         4       5          4        5
> ```

**Follow up question**

Eventually I'll need to do this in SQL but that seems too hard. I heard that the 'dbply' package could help me here because if I can solve this using the dplyr functions then it will somehow convert that to a valid SQL query?

Comment: I really don't understand the mapping between your input and output, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure, it's a little complicated, sorry. Basically I want to know for given day, which task should each person be working on. So, the main condition (1) is if a higher numbered task overlaps a lower numbered task for a give person, then the lower number task should be removed (i.e. should be made NA). (2) If there is no overlap, then then I need to work out how long the person should work on the lower numbered task. Does that help?

Comment: slightly. definitely looks like `foverlaps` from `data.table` will be your friend.

Comment: you said "task number", but used letters? and it seems alphabetically subsequent letters have the higher rank?

Comment: this problem looks inherently recursive to me. step one declare intervals for highest ranked tasks. step two go in order of rank assigning as much of the task as feasible, truncating as needed (to NA as last resort).

Comment: are the start and end times always integers (or at least trumcated to one digit)? bounded?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes, sorry, English is not my first language. (1)  I have renamed now. (2) Yes, higher letters means higher priority. (3) The start and end times are always integers (in the real problem they are dates). (4) Yes, bounded. :)

Comment: I removed the SQL tag from this question, because it is clearly about R.  When "eventually" comes, then ask another question, and provide information relevant to a SQL solution -- such as the database you are working on.  Depending on the database, this might not be that hard in SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) package. `map2` and `unnest` are to expand the dataset. `arrange(person, desc(task_key))` and `distinct(person, Days, .keep_all = TRUE)` are to remove duplicates based on the order of `task_key`. After that, we can use `slice` to select the last row and manipulate the start and end dates.

```
library(tidyverse)

output_df <- input_df %>%
  mutate(Days = map2(start_day, end_day, `:`)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  arrange(person, desc(task_key)) %>%
  distinct(person, Days, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(person, task_key, Days) %>%
  group_by(person, task_key) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  mutate(end_day = ifelse(Days < end_day, Days + 1L, end_day)) %>%
  select(-Days) %>%
  rename(valid_from = start_day, valid_to = end_day) %>%
  right_join(input_df, by = c("person", "task_key")) %>%
  select(names(input_df), starts_with("valid")) %>%
  ungroup()
output_df
# # A tibble: 11 x 6
#    person task_key start_day end_day valid_from valid_to
#    <fct>  <fct>        <int>   <int>      <int>    <int>
#  1 Kate   A                1       5         NA       NA
#  2 Kate   B                1       5          1        5
#  3 Adam   A                1       5          1        2
#  4 Adam   B                2       5          2        5
#  5 Eve    A                2       5         NA       NA
#  6 Eve    B                1       5          1        5
#  7 Jason  A                1       5          1        3
#  8 Jason  B                4       5         NA       NA
#  9 Jason  C                3       5          3        4
# 10 Jason  D                5       5         NA       NA
# 11 Jason  E                4       5          4        5
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I had to do something similar earlier in the week but in a different context.

A solution using just the `dplyr` package is presented below (there is a warning at step 10 but I think it can be ignored).

In terms of converting this `dplyr` solution into a `dbplyr` solution with associated valid SQL code is something I don't know how to do (I gave it a go but it didn't work).

**EDIT**: In the original version of your question you had numbers instead of letters for your task key which is what I used. I didn't see you had edited your question until after I posted :)

**Code with comments:**

```
# Load packages.
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(RSQLite)
library(RPostgreSQL)

# Data
input_df <- data.frame(person        = c(rep("Kate", 2), rep("Adam", 2), rep("Eve", 2), rep("Jason", 5)),
                       task_key      = c(1:2, 1:2, 1:2, 1:5),
                       start_day     = c(c(1L,1L), c(1L,2L), c(2L,1L), c(1L,4L,3L,5L,4L)),
                       end_day       = 5L)


# [OPTIONAL] Convert to a databse; I couldn't figure out how to make an in-memory verson of PostgreSQL using RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL()
#            If this worked, then you could use the show_query() function to see the SQL it generates.
#con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
#DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "input_df", input_df)
#input_df <- tbl(con, "input_df")


# Step 01: Keep only minimal information.
df01 <- input_df %>%
  select(person, task_key, start_day) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  dplyr::rename(tk=task_key, sd=start_day) 
# show_query(df01)


# Step 02: Explode table with all pair-wise comparisons for each person.
df02 <- left_join(x = df01, y = df01, by = c("person"), suffix =  c(".bas", ".alt"))
# show_query(df02)

# Step 03: Remove self-comparisons
df03 <- filter(.data = df02, tk.bas != tk.alt)
# show_query(df03)

# Step 04: Add a flag to indicate when the baseline task takes priority over the comparator.
df04 <- mutate(.data = df03, tk.bas_priority = tk.bas > tk.alt) # check inequality
# show_query(df04)

# Step 05: Add a flag to indicate when the baseline date is earlier then the comparator date.
df05 <- mutate(.data = df04, sd.bas_earliest = sd.bas < sd.alt)
# show_query(df05)

# Step 06: Is it possible to reduce the number of comparisons? 
#          I think there is a way but haven't looked into it.
df06 <- df05
# show_query(df06)

# Step 07: Organise columns to make them easier for me to read.
df07 <- select(.data = df06, person, tk.bas, tk.alt, tk.bas_priority, sd.bas, sd.alt, sd.bas_earliest)
# show_query(df07)

# Step 08: Group table by person and baseline date.
df08 <- group_by(.data = df07, person, tk.bas) 
# show_query(df08)

# Step 09: Create start dates.
df09 <- df08 %>%
  mutate(start = case_when(
    tk.bas_priority == TRUE  & sd.bas_earliest == TRUE  ~ sd.bas,
    tk.bas_priority == TRUE  & sd.bas_earliest == FALSE ~ sd.bas,
    tk.bas_priority == FALSE & sd.bas_earliest == TRUE  ~ sd.bas,
    tk.bas_priority == FALSE & sd.bas_earliest == FALSE ~ NA_integer_,
    TRUE                                        ~ -1L
  ))  %>%
  mutate(start = as.integer(min(start, na.rm = FALSE))) 
# show_query(df09)

# Step 10: Create end dates. 
# Note: This will create warnings because empty vectors might be applied to 'min' or 'max'. 
#       I think these can be ignored because it doesn't matter in this case?
df10 <- df09 %>%
  mutate(end = case_when(
    tk.bas_priority == TRUE  & sd.bas_earliest == TRUE ~ as.integer(max(sd.alt)),
    tk.bas_priority == TRUE  & sd.bas_earliest == FALSE ~ as.integer(max(sd.alt)),
    tk.bas_priority == FALSE & sd.bas_earliest == TRUE ~ as.integer(min(sd.alt[tk.bas_priority == F])),
    tk.bas_priority == FALSE & sd.bas_earliest == FALSE ~ NA_integer_,
    TRUE                                   ~ -1L
  )) %>%
  mutate(end = as.integer(min(end, na.rm = FALSE))) 
# show_query(df10)

# Step 11: Ungroup table.
df11 <- ungroup(df10)
# show_query(df11)

# Step 12: Reduce table to distinct start/end values for each person and baseline ad.
df12 <- df11 %>%
  select(person, tk.bas, start, end) %>%
  distinct()
# show_query(df12)

# Step 13: Join back onto original data.
df13 <- left_join(input_df, df12, by = c("person"="person", "task_key"="tk.bas"))
# show_query(df13)

# Step 14: Account for the end date for the final row per person
df14 <- df13 %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  mutate(end = if_else(row_number() == n(), as.integer(max(end_day)), end)) %>% 
  ungroup()
# show_query(df14)
# collect(df14)
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 11 x 6
   person task_key start_day end_day start   end
   <fct>     <int>     <int>   <int> <int> <int>
 1 Kate          1         1       5    NA    NA
 2 Kate          2         1       5     1     5
 3 Adam          1         1       5     1     2
 4 Adam          2         2       5     2     5
 5 Eve           1         2       5    NA    NA
 6 Eve           2         1       5     1     5
 7 Jason         1         1       5     1     3
 8 Jason         2         4       5    NA    NA
 9 Jason         3         3       5     3     4
10 Jason         4         5       5    NA    NA
11 Jason         5         4       5     4     5
```